# XSLT Ordering Output off an attribute

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following example XML:

```
<Table>
  <Row Position="0" Name="FName" />
  <Row Position="1" Name="LName" />
  <Row Position="2" Name="Email" />
  <Row Position="3" Name="Phone" />
  <Row Position="4" Name="Address" />
</Table>
```

I want to be able to read this into an output of:

```
Row: FName
Row: LName
Row: Email
Row: Phone
Row: Address
```

The ordering for this list however should be based off the `Position` attribute of the row, so that the output order can be changed by simply changing the number ordering.

I guess this will take a variable or two to complete but not entirely sure on the execution.

Cheers

Example:

Input

```
<Table>
  <Row Position="0" Name="FName" />
  <Row Position="1" Name="LName" />
  <Row Position="4" Name="Email" />
  <Row Position="2" Name="Phone" />
  <Row Position="3" Name="Address" />
</Table>
```

Output

```
Row: FName
Row: LName
Row: Phone
Row: Address
Row: Email
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<xsl:template match="Table">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="Row">
    <xsl:sort select="@Position" data-type="number"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Row">
  <xsl:text>Row: </xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="@Name"/>
  <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Works fine ty, will look into sort for the future